# Scala Quill error when using infix

Tags: scala, dsl, scala-macros, quill.io

I run into problem when using `Quill`'s infix operation .
`Scala` 2.12.4 
`Quill` 2.3.3

```
import io.getquill._
val ctx = new SqlMirrorContext(PostgresDialect, SnakeCase)
import ctx._

// infix for custom DB operation
implicit class StringQuotes(left: String) {
  def equalTest(right: String): Quoted[Boolean] = quote {
    infix"$left = $right".as[Boolean]
  }
}

case class User(name: String)

object User {
  // normal usage 
  def filter1() = quote {
    query[User]
      .filter(
        user => user.name == "Cool"
      )
  }
  //using infix for custom operation
  def filter2() = quote {
    query[User]
      .filter(
        user => user.name equalTest "Cool"
      )
  }
}
//pass, and generates a valid SQL.
ctx.run(User.filter1())

// fail
ctx.run(User.filter2())
```

The error message is obscure:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: value user
..... too long to show
Error while emitting main.scala
```

It only indicate `filter2` is cause, and doesn't say which line wrong.

Runnable code snippet at `Scastie` online editor https://scastie.scala-lang.org/superChing/haYVkGLDSlKsOhYlaPdO1w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works without explicit return type `Quoted[Boolean]` in `equalTest` function :

```
def equalTest(right: String) = quote {
    infix"$left = $right".as[Boolean]
}
```

Comment: do you have reason or documentation about it?

Comment: I think that Quoted can exist only inside context, but your Quoted return type is unbounded. But mysterious Scala can interfere correct Quoted return type for you, if you omit it :)